# Create a Bitbucket Repo with SSH through their API

Tags: api, ssh, bitbucket

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repository-resource-423626331.html

I'm looking at the API documentation in order to make a private repo with a shell script. I'd like to use SSH and not have to enter my username and password.

Is this possible at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Bitbucket REST API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html) supports http(s), but not ssh. Git can work over ssh, but that's something entirely different from the Bitbucket API.

To update/retrieve private info in Bitbucket, you need to be [authenticated](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html#UsetheBitbucketCloudRESTAPIs-Authentication). The options you have are either basic authentication with the credentials of a user with sufficient permissions (not what you want), or OAuth, which might be appropriate for you.

How to use OAuth is documented [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html).